# Google Maps API / JavaScript centering variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using basic geolocation to grab user long/lat, I then add the coordinate pair to a global variable (global.usr), then generating a new map element with global.usr as my center of the map.

Seems pretty straight forward, returned with a grey, blank, Google maps element.

```html
var x = document.getElementById("alert");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
    } else {
        alert("You don't support this");
    }
}
getLocation();


var global = {};

    function showPosition(position)
    {
  global.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude
    );
    }



var mapElement = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
  center: global.coords,
  zoom: 4
});
```

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);` the first argument to the getCurrentPosition method is the callback to run when the coordinates are successfully received, passing the position as the first parameter. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition . I am guessing you want that line to actually be `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);`, but that still won't work, because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous - there is no guarantee it will complete before you define the map variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, it looks like you meant to supply `showPosition`, not `getLocation` as the param to `getCurrentPosition`. You also need to take into account that the `getCurrentPosition` method is non-blocking - so getLocation will return immediately and you will progress to defining the map element before you actually have the coords. I think you actually want something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("alert"), 
    mapElement = document.getElementById("map-canvas"), 
    map;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
    } else {
        alert("You don't support this");
    }
}
getLocation();


var global = {};

function showPosition(position)
{
    global.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
        position.coords.latitude,
        position.coords.longitude
    );
    defineMap();
}

function defineMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
      center: global.coords,
      zoom: 4
    });
}
```

You can get more information about the `getCurrentPosition` method here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition